# How to deal with this kind of question

Tags: discussion

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18960689/ubuntu-says-bash-program-permission-denied), the OP ask for some knowledge about how perform some jobs in **Ubuntu** and it was marked as **closed**. And I remembered that I flag a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299989/x11-xlib-h-not-found-in-ubuntu) as 'need moderators' attention: to move it to askUbuntu'.

I think this kind of question are useful and easy to find in a specific website so I suggest for moving. Besides, some closed question may be deleted in the future. So I did it (flag to move).

Am I wrong about it?

Comment: Questions can't be migrated if they are more than 60 days old. That one's from 2013, so long past that threshold.

Comment: Oh, I understand it. So I have to mark it off-topic. Thanks.

Comment: @Mat Why not? Why 60?

Comment: Some info here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days @bjb568